# AVAudioConverter's channelMap results in lower pitch

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, core-audio

I'm using `AVAudioConverter` to convert audio between formats, and I've come across an issue where the pitch of my audio becomes lower under a specific condition.

Input format is uncompressed two channel audio:

> Sample Rate: 48000.0 Hz, Channels: 2, Format: int16, Interleaved, Non-standard, AudioFormatID: kAudioFormatLinearPCM (1819304813), Settings: ["AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey": 16, "AVFormatIDKey": 1819304813, "AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved": 0, "AVNumberOfChannelsKey": 2, "AVSampleRateKey": 48000, "AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey": 0, "AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey": 0]

Output format is compressed two channel audio:

> Sample Rate: 48000.0 Hz, Channels: 2, Format: other, Interleaved, Non-standard, AudioFormatID: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC (1633772320), Settings: ["AVSampleRateKey": 48000, "AVFormatIDKey": 1633772320, "AVNumberOfChannelsKey": 2]

When I set the `channelMap` of the converter to use the same input channel for both output channels, the pitch of the resulting audio is affected. Here's what I'm seeing:

- `converter.channelMap = [0, -1]` : sounds fine, but only left ear audio
- `converter.channelMap = [-1, 1]` : sounds fine, but only right ear audio
- `converter.channelMap = [0, 0]` : results in a lowered pitch

Interestingly, when I use the channel mapping for a mono output format, it works perfectly. My goal is to do the same for the stereo format. I need to keep both output channels in case the user will change the channel map to [0, 1].

What could be causing the pitch alteration when using the same input channel for both output channels in stereo?

Comment: Is the pitch alteration happening with any input file/signal?

Comment: yes with any, I get the input from microphone of an iPhone

Comment: I would start by checking if the signal is what you expect before converting. ["An iOS device’s built-in microphone input consists of an array of physical microphones and beamformers"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/capturing_stereo_audio_from_built-in_microphones) where you need to select stereo as a "PolarPattern".

Comment: Maybe you should post your code, otherwise it's just guessing..

Comment: Is it just a slight pitch drop or is it all around half pitch? (i.e. like you have selected playback speed to be 0.5)